# Convert Datetime format to Date from sql and bind to Gridview only date

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

```
using (con = new SqlConnection(con_str))
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = "select mcfact as Factory, mcarea as Department, mcloc as Location, mcroom as Room, mcline as Line, cast (scanned as date) from tb_MachineRecord where mcidno='" + cmbmcidno.Text + "' ";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView7.DataSource = ds;
    GridView7.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Using this code the output is with time like `03/05/2016 00:00:00` but when I run this query in SQL it's showing the correct output like `2016-05-03`

Comment: You can change the formatting in your datagrid

Comment: `cast (scanned as date)` is your date column?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ds you can use dt object of datatable 
for example :

```
 using (con = new SqlConnection(con_str))
    {
    con.Open();
    string sql = "select mcfact as Factory, mcarea as Department, mcloc as Location, mcroom as Room, mcline as Line, cast (scanned as date) as date from tb_MachineRecord where mcidno='" + cmbmcidno.Text + "' ";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    Datatable dt=new datatable();
    da.Fill(dt);

   foreach(DataRow rows in dt.rows.Count)
   {
      rows["date"]=Convert.ToDateTime(rows["date"].toString()).toString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
   }
    GridView7.DataSource = dt;
    GridView7.DataBind();
    con.Close();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `BoundFields` you can do this

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="myDBdate" DataFormatString="{0:f}" />
```

See the [Microsoft Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) for more BoundField DateTime formats.

If you use `TemplateFields` you can do this:

```
<ItemTemplate><%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myDBdate")).ToShortDateString() %></ItemTemplate>
```

See the [Microsoft Site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more DateTime formats

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
select name,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date_of_birth,120) from tbl_Login
```

**date_of_birth** is datetime type column

Answer (score 0):

```
using (con = new SqlConnection(con_str))
{
    con.Open();
    string sql = "select mcfact as Factory, mcarea as Department, mcloc as Location, mcroom as Room, mcline as Line, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),scanned,120) from tb_MachineRecord where mcidno='" + cmbmcidno.Text + "' ";
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView7.DataSource = ds;
    GridView7.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```